# Generate a .csv file using jersey restful webservice

Tags: csv, jersey

I am trying to generate a `.csv` file as response to a restful webservice(using Jersey). So far, I am able to get a `List<HashMap<String, String>>` and the key should be the CSV header and value should be the CSV data.

I am using the Jackson API for CSV generation.
The code flow is:

1. I get the data from DAO class in `List<HashMap<String, String>>` name of the list is `myArrList`.
   My first doubt is is this a good idea to provide the file location like this in real scenario? How else can I do this? How can I send a file with data without actually creating a file in local system?

   ```java
   File file = new File( "C:/Users/.../Downloads/RadioObjectData.csv");
   Writer writer = null;
   ResponseBuilder response = null;
   Reader reader = null;

   //Copy List of Map Object into CSV format at specified File location.
   try
   {
        writer = new FileWriter( file, false);
        reader = new FileReader( file);
        csvWriter( myArrList, writer);
        // csvReader( reader);
        response = Response.ok( (Object)file);
        response.header( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"RadioObjectData.csv\"");
        // return response.build();
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
   //Read CSV format from specified File location and print on console..
   return response.build();
   ```

   and now I send this `List` to the `csvWriter` method to create a `.csv` file in my system so that then I can send this same file as response to the webservice.(Is this approach ok?)

   ```java
   public static void csvWriter( List<HashMap<String, String>> listOfMap, Writer writer) throws IOException
   {
     CsvSchema schema = null;
     CsvSchema.Builder schemaBuilder = CsvSchema.builder();
     if (listOfMap != null && !listOfMap.isEmpty())
     {
        for (String col: listOfMap.get( 0).keySet())
        {
           schemaBuilder.addColumn( col);
        }
        schema = schemaBuilder.build().withLineSeparator( "\r").withHeader();
     }
     CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
     mapper.writer( schema).writeValues( writer).writeAll( listOfMap);
     writer.flush();
   }
   ```
2. Now a `.csv` file is getting created in my `C` drive at the given location.
   I want this CSV to be encoded in *base64* before sending it as a response.

How can I achieve all of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a [`StreamingOutput`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/StreamingOutput.html) as the `Response` entity.

```java
interface StreamingOutput {
    void write(OutputStream out);
}
```

You just implement this interface and pass it to the `Response.ok()` method. What you would do in this case is just wrap the `OutputStream` in a `OutputStreamWriter`, so that you can pass it to the `CsvMapper.writeValues(Writer)` method.

```java
StreamingOutput entity = new StreamingOutput() {
    @Override
    public void write(OutputStream out) {
        Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(out, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        csvWriter(myArrList, writer);
        out.flush();
    }
};
return Response.ok(entity)
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
                "attachment; filename=\"RadioObjectData.csv\"")
        .build();
```

That's all you need. No need to any intermediate storage.

#### Update

If you want to Base64 encode the CSV file, what you can do is write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and use those byte to encode with the [`Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) class. After it is encoded, just write the encoded bytes to the `StreamingOutput` `OutputStream`. Here is an example.

```java
StreamingOutput entity = new StreamingOutput() {
    @Override
    public void write(OutputStream out) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter baosWriter = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(baos, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        csvWriter(myArrList, baosWriter);
        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
        byte[] base64Encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes);

        out.write(base64Encoded);
        out.flush();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you ! one more question I asked about base64 encoding.Any comments for that? If yes please let me know

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It adds unnecessary complexity for the client the decode it.

Comment: Even I am not sure why it is required.but i am asked to do so and I am only responsible for server part of the service .so I am just providing what is asked from me :)

Comment: The only way I can think is to put the whole csv file into a string and then encode it. If I were you, I would question why they want to do it. It makes no sense. You would only need to base64 if you were using some binary format that you need to turn into a text format for transport. It makes no sense in this case.

Comment: I am new to encoding thing.I thought they are asking it for secure data transfer over web service. Is it safe to transfer data in csv format without any encoding?

Comment: base64 is not secure. If it's sensitive data, then it should be _encrypted_. That's different from base64 encoding. If it's over SSL, then it will already be encrypted.

Comment: If you really want to do it, where's what I would do. Use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and wrap it with a `OutputStreamWriter`. Use the Csv write to write to this. They get the bytes from the BAOS and [encode it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html). Then write those bytes to the StreamingOutput OutputStream

Comment: I tried your method.Now my csv file is generated has only one line .is this the correct thing? is this how base64 encoded data looks like?Apologies if my question is too silly!!!

Comment: I checked online .this is how base64 encoded data looks like but only issue is all the data coming in one line in the generated csv file.so when i try to decode this file online(base64 to csv decoding (https://onlinecsvtools.com/convert-base64-to-csv)) it says invalid base64 data.

Comment: Yes, this is it. Anything you encode to base64 will only be one line string.

Comment: oh ok. then it will be a problem for the client to decode it and sue the data further?